# Is there a way to view history on an entire folder in Borland StarTeam?

Tags: version-control, starteam

I'm trying to obtain an aggregate checkin history for an entire folder but haven't figured out a way to do this using the StarTeam client. I'm using StarTeam 2005 R2. Is this supported in a later version or is it something I'd need to use the StarTeam api to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The History in StarTeam is managed by item.
If you wish to review the checkin-history of *all* items in a folder,
you will have to do it one-by-one.